# Serializing specific fields from another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I was trying to serialize policy_length, coverage_amount from Policy model and use it in a serializer that was using Insuree model.

I'm using Policy and Insuree models:

**Policy model**

```
class Policy(TimeStampedModel):

 policy_length = models.FloatField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
 coverage_amount = models.FloatField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Insuree model**

```
class Insuree(TimeStampedModel):
 user = models.OneToOneField(
    'User', related_name='insuree', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True)
 coverage_amount = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
 policy_length = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

class PolicySelectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Insuree
    fields = ('age', 'gender', 'disposable_income') #Current fields

    fields = ('age','gender',disposable_income', 'policy_length', 'coverage_amount') #The field I need and want to do
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You may use Nested Serializer.

```
 PolicySerializer(ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ( 'policy_length', 'coverage_amount')


 InsureeSerializer(ModelSerializer)
       class Meta:
          policy = PolicySerializer(many = True)
          model = Insuree
          fields = ('age', 'gender', 'disposable_income', 'policy',)
```